# Create a graphic with xls using Pylab in Python

Tags: csv, matplotlib, xls, graphic

I'm using Python 3.4.1. I want to create a graphic using xls files instead of csv. How can I do ? Can I create a graphic using xls files without converting them ?

```
from pylab import* 
name = []
value = []

readFile = open('fichier_test.xls', 'r').read()
eachline = readFile.split('\n')
for line in eachline:
    split = line.split(';')
    name.append()
    value.append(split[1])
    value.append(float(split[1]))

pos = arange(len(name))+.5
barh(pos, value, align='center',color='blue')
yticks(pos, name)
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xlrd` [library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) for python to import the data. To print all the rows in your datasheet,

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('fichier_test.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
for row in range(num_rows):
    print(worksheet.row(row))
```

You can then extract, plot, etc with matplotlib.